# What do you add to damage rolls? (5e)

Tags: dnd-5e, attack

Say you have a level 1 character (so a proficiency bonus of +2) and that character is proficient in ranged martial weapons and they have a dexterity of 16 (+3). If they attack using a longbow then they add 5 to their attack roll. But for damage do they add 5 or do damage rolls just include the ability modifier of +3?

Comment: Ah so you don't add proficiency to damage?

Comment: Correct. Proficiency only ever adds to rolls with the 20-sided die (attacks, skills, abilities, saves, etc)

Comment: Related: [How do I figure the dice and bonuses for attack rolls and damage rolls?](/questions/72910)